# Send data from MATLAB to local website

Tags: javascript, html, json, matlab, http

I have a MATLAB GUI which creates a lot of plots.

Now I want to show these plots on a local website --> HTML/JS file. 
My idea is to send the data to my browser/website like Client/Server and then plot the charts there.

But how can I pass/send the Data from Matlab to my local website? 
Is there any HTTP way or something like websockets?

Thanks very much!
Best regards
Ralph

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always use Matlab's built in networking capabilities, or external libraries.

- [HTTP Requests](https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.net.http.requestmessage.send.html)
- [Custom Matlab WebSocket library](https://github.com/jebej/MatlabWebSocket)
- [Raw TCP socket](https://de.mathworks.com/help/instrument/communicate-using-tcpip-server-sockets.html)

Then I presume you can listen on your client/server side and send the necessary action (i.e. plot your data with whatever graphing library you are using).

I'm not sure if you are aware of [plotly](https://plot.ly/matlab/), but they do online plots (nicer than matlab basic graphs in my opinion) that look like the native Matlab ones.

You can also [generate the plots on a URL](https://plot.ly/matlab/user-guide/) using just Matlab, so in theory you wouldn't have to do any of the graph plotting logic yourself! - you just redirect the user to the URL link hosting the plot (I think it may require a premium account though); here's a [getting started link](https://plot.ly/matlab/getting-started/).

---

**EDIT 1:**

So you can format your data in whichever format you like and then send it via the HTTP request I linked before.

Example : Formulate your data into JSON encoded data, send it via your chosen method (HTTP/TCP/WebSockets), and then plot it on your browser with JS.

Turn your data into JSON (Matlab's [JSON encoder](https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/jsonencode.html)):

```
data = 1:3;
dataJsonString = jsonencode(data); % Returns : "{1,2,3}"
```

Create a webwrite (RESTFul web service):

```
body.data = dataJsonString;
options = weboptions('MediaType', 'application/json');
resp = webwrite('http://yourwebsite.com', body, options); % When you press your button in Matlab you want to run everything I have just written
```

And then in wherever you handle your server side `onDataReceived`, update your plot by parsing whatever data you just received via JSON.

Comment: Hey WoodyDev, 
thanks for your answer. 
Plotly is not the right thing, I already plot my data on the website, because in the moment, I save the data in a JSON file and then load the data with my HTML file. But I want to send the data directly. 

Is it possible to send the data with the HTTP Request without a request, so pressing on a button in Matlab and send it to my website? 
I will also try your Custom Matlab WebSocket library, thanks!

Comment: Hi @R.Homm I just updated my answer with an example of an implementation :-)

Comment: Thanks very much, I'll try this and let you know, if I have any problems! Is that also possible if I have my website still in a html file, so 'http://yourwebsite.com' would be 'file:///C:/myfile.html'? Thanks!